# GIT Weekly Activity

Tags: git, report, git-diff, git-bash, git-log

I would like to generate a weekly GIT report, where I can see how many code has been submitted  and deleted by each developer in specific timeframe.

**The purpose is to get general overview of developers activity in specific timeframe**

- Start date
- End date
- Developer
- Commits
- Added code
- Deleted code

It would be great if I can export these information into csv

```
[some-script/command] > weekly-git-log.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of changes for specific user in specific date range - Each file details

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h,%an,%ad,%s" --author=example@email.com --since=2012-11-19 --until=2012-11-20 --date=short --numstat
```

List of changes for specific user in specific date range - Commit summary

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h,%an,%ad,%s" --author=example@email.com --since=2012-11-19 --until=2012-11-20 --date=short --shortstat
```

**Final short version**

```
git log --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ad%x09%Cblue%s" --date=short --author=example@email.com --shortstat --since=2012-11-19 --until=2012-11-20
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd start with `git log --since="1 week ago" --until="now"` and [customize it to your heart's content](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Example:

`git log --since="1 week ago" --until="now" --format="%an,%ct,%s" > weekly-git-log.csv`

You aren't being very specific about what you want to store in the CSV file, so I'm giving you a very general answer and letting you fill in the details yourself.

**EDIT**:

If you want to get lines added/removed, you're going to have to get a bit fancier and use a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
DATA=(`git log --since="1 week ago" --until="now" --format="%ct,%an,%s,"`)
LINES=(`git log --since="1 week ago" --until="now" --pretty=tformat: --shortstat | gawk '(NF > 0){ printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$4 }' -`)

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#DATA[@]} ]; do
    echo "${DATA[$i]}${LINES[$i]}"
    i=$[i + 1]
done
```

I'm throwing in lines added/removed after the message, since it's easier to do in the script (I'm not THAT great with bash). This should be a pretty good foundation for what you want to do. (call `./script.sh >file.csv` to output to a file)

Note that commas in the commit message will break your csv file, I'd change the commas in the `--format` to some obscure character that can't be regularly typed on a keyboard, scrub out any commas in the message, then substitute commas for that obscure character.

Or you can just do away with `%s` in the format too if you don't need the message.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have specified what I am exactly looking for:
 - Start date
 - End date
 - Developer
 - Commits
 - Added code
 - Deleted code

Your command includes just some of those.
I need generate table with this information:
Date | Developer Name | Added | Deleted| Commit message

Eventually I need not to setup start and end date since I am able to easily filtrate this in Excel.

Comment: Added a script that should get you a lot closer to what you want. Again, look through the git log man page, especially the formatting section, and fine-tune this script to whatever you need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --since="1 week ago" --until="now" \
--format="%an,%ct,%s" > git_log_11_17_2012-11_24_2012.csv
```

Note that "1 week ago" can be done with exactly that text "1 week ago" (so it's not a placeholder for a real date though that could be used too) thanks to approxidate

Comment: Thanks! Exactly same as previous one. I need to generate more sophisticated table. BTW: Edit your command than it is just for one line.. Now it do not work for copy paste.

Comment: I added the "\" line continuation character.  btw it's not exactly the same as previous, for instance the "=" was missing in the previous (but got added after I posted mine...)